# Handle resolution of different size images in listview

Tags: android

I am getting different size images from server and setting in list-view but while maintaining resolution of images some get blur. I am loading a images using lazy-list concept.

```
Approximate size of my images.
width height
783    435
108     68
320    179
72      54
596    335
```

Below Method is used to handle the images resolution.

```
  private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);
      //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=50;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=2;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

And if I remove or changes to **o2.inSampleSize=1** then it wont work in Galaxy SII.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the error u r getting for galaxy s2. Can u post it

Comment: -Andro Selva That's a second issue first issue is images get blur. anyway will edit my question and post it.

Comment: @AndroSelva 11-15 12:29:50.567: E/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget. this error I am getting in galaxy SII

Comment: Well, one thing is scaling avoids this outOfmemory issue but as you said this will lead to image blurness which is not avoidable. But if you still want your images to look good then you have to handle outofmemory exception. There are plenty number of questions posted abt it. Please take a look at those.