# When we click ListView button at position 1, the button at the10th position is also clicked

Tags: android, custom-adapter

I have a problem with my listView. I displayed the list item using a custom adapter class.
My problem is, when I click on the listview button at the position 1, the button at position 10 is also clicked. How do I overcome this problem?

Here is my code:

```
public static class Clockin_Group extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;


    public Clockin_Group(Context context) {
         mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
          this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {         

         if(employeeList==null){
                return 0;
            }
            else{
                return employeeList.length;
            }

    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {           
        return employeeList[position];
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {           
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;    

         if (convertView == null){
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_clkin_row, null);
             holder = new ViewHolder();
             convertView.setTag(holder);

         }

         else{
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
          }


         holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
            holder.tv.setText(employeeList[position]);
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.loc_id_tv);
            holder.tv1.setText("["+empNo_Array[position]+"]");
            holder.check = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkmark);
       holder.check.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            holder.time.setText("Last Clock " +punchType_array[position]+" "+"at"+" "+punchTime_array[position]);                   
            holder.clkin_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_clockin);
      holder.clkin_tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_button);

            holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    employee_id = Integer.parseInt(emp_idList[position]);
                       emp_selected = employeeList[position];
                       System.out.println("selected Emp.."+emp_selected);

                    boolean Status = false;
                       String type = "In";
                       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                          Date date=new Date();
                          String s=sdf.format(date);
                          System.out.println("GMT: "+s);


                      try {
                            Status = sendDetails(corpId, user_name, password,employee_id,location_id_str, task_id_str, "0", type);
                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {                   
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {                   
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {                 
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                       if(Status){

                            holder.button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                               holder.clkin_tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                               holder.time.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#088A08"));
                               holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                               holder.time.setText("Last Clock IN at "+sdf.format(new Date()).toString());
                               System.out.println("Status..");
                       }                       

                       else{
                           Toast.makeText(context, "Clock In Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           holder.button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                              holder.clkin_tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                          }


                }
            });
            /*convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                //private int pos = position;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  //Toast.makeText(context, "Click-" + String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                }
              });*/

            convertView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, employeeList[position]+"["+empNo_Array[position]+"]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
          //  convertView.setTag(holder);



        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162835/button-events-in-listview

Comment: How did you solve this? Tags?

Comment: Unable to follow your code, tv, tv1, clkin_tv abbrevations are making it impossible to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Check by setting your listView height and width wrap_content or fill_parent.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, every button in list is going to have same id.
Instead of writing `onClik()` in base adapter you can write `onItemClickListener()` in your activity which will give you position of the item in `ListView`.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP needs, they seem to be wanting to have an onClick for a button inside the listview cell, not a click for the listview item.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use tags.

ie

```
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

then inside your onClick get the tag and action from there

```
String currentPos = arg0.getTag().toString();
Integer.parseInt(currentPos)
```

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

actually `convertView`  concept is used to reuse the view and there are 10 views are being created initially and when you scroll the list `onclick` listener is not being update.

you can use [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive) to assign different `onClickListener` to each of your items

Answer (score 0):

Set the tag with position key not with holder.

Change

```
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

to

```
convertView.setTag(position);
```

chk..

Comment: I am getting Exception by using yur code...                       07-27 12:28:15.798: E/AndroidRuntime(700): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
07-27 12:28:15.798: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at com.android.epay.TestClass1$Clockin_Group.getView(TestClass1.java:559)
07-27 12:28:15.798: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
I am getting Exception by using yur code...android.widget.ListView.addViewBelow(ListView.java:2896)
07-27 12:28:15.798: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at

Comment: How is this going to help ?

Answer (score 0):

//  Write one set function inside adapter

```
public void setList(List<Employee> list) {
    mEmployeeList = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
} 

//Create a member variable. 
private List<Employee> mEmployeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

//Now in getView()

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    /Use like this

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
     final Employee employee= mEmployeeList.get(position);
```

//Use employee to set all variable.

```
     holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

      @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
     Log.i("Adapter", employee.id);
       }});
}
```

// Call setList function from your main class pass employeeList and let me know the result.